# Can't get Intern to run their own tutorial

Tags: intern

I'm  new to NodeJS and even more for Intern trying to learn intern for testing at work but can't start intern-client by their own tutorial step-by-step, it is giving me back always the error:

```
C:\testproject\root>node ./node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=tests/intern
C:\testproject\root\node_modules\.bin\intern-client:2
basedir=`dirname "$0"`
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I was following the Quick Start from their site https://github.com/theintern/intern and after creating the folders, installing intern through NodeJS and adding their example into the tests/folder. Running their script was not helpful to determinate what is wrong with their tutorial. Set the packages and non functional suites based on their example but still have no success.

```
//...
loader: {
    // Packages that should be registered with the loader in each testing environment
    packages: [ { name: 'root', location: '.' } ],
    // map: { 'intern-selftest': { dojo: 'intern-selftest/node_modules/dojo' } }
},

// Non-functional test suite(s) to run in each browser
suites: [ 'root/tests/intern' ],
//...
```

I nuked the entire project several time, used jslint and jshint and got no syntax errors back.
Also tried some unsuccessful combinations with :

https: //github.com/theintern/intern-tutorial

https: //gist.github.com/neonstalwart/6630466

Any ideas or a REALLY working example available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you putting `node` at the start of the command? None of the documentation says to do that. You’re trying to run a shell script with Node.js (which, to be clear, Intern **did not** create that shell script, your installer did), which will never work because JavaScript and sh are not the same language.